# awk parts of a column if the value is equal or lower than

Tags: bash, csv, awk

```
awk '$7<=0.05 {print $7}' statusResults.csv > statusResults_sign.csv
```

This produces an empty output. If the value in column 7 is lower or equal to 0.05 I want to write it to a new file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the field separator as you have a CSV file.  Try this:

```
awk -F, 'NR>1 && $7<=0.05 { print $7 }' test.txt
```

I also skipped over the header line; not sure if you want that too.

Comment: Perfect! But what if want to print $7 AND $1, also I want the headers. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Show us some input data. Your command seems to be ok.

```
cat file
0.06
0.05
0.04
0.08
0.02
```

Running awk

```
awk '$1<=0.05' file
0.05
0.04
0.02
```

Comment: "","baseMean","log2FoldChange","lfcSE","stat","pvalue","padj"
"1/2-SBSRNA4",23.3545024897891,-0.377171574987616,0.213675562828429,-1.76516008660506,0.0775368645420287,0.999500994113898
"A1BG",56.0422521776373,0.202983318553928,0.172128788396789,1.17925258432664,0.238297612833129,0.999500994113898

Comment: Its the column "padj" I want.